# Does kafka client connect to zookeeper or is it behind the scene

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Kafka client code directly refers to the broker ip and port and in case if it is down will zookeeper direct to another broker. is zookeper always behind the scene

Answer (score 1):

In the case you provide only one broker address in the client code, and it goes down, plus your client restarts, then your client will also be down. Zookeeper will not be used here because the broker will not be reachable.

If you give more than one broker address in the client, then it's more resilient in that the Kafka Controller process periodically fetches a list of all alive brokers in the cluster from Zookeeper and is responsible for sending that information back to the clients via the leader of the partitions they get assigned. Zookeeper is indirectly used here, but does not communicate with any external clients

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question in the right way the answer is no.
The Kafka clients need connection only to Kafka brokers and Zookeeper isn't involved at all. Clients needs to write/read leader partitions on brokers.
If the Kafka brokers set in the brokers list aren't available, the clients can connect and cannot start to send/receive messages.
Only in the old version 0.8.0 the Zookeeper was involved for consumers which saved offset on Zookeeper. Starting from 0.9.0, the consumers save offset in Kafka topics so Zookeeper isn't needed anymore.

Comment: Zookeeper is still "involved" and "needed", just not by the clients

Comment: yeah sure. I just referred to clients and the question was referring ;)